# Moving odb pragmas outside class header

Tags: c++, odb

Is way to move odb (c++ orm like framework) pragmas outside class header?
For example I define class basic_object (abstract) with id only:

```
class basic_object  {
   int _id;
public:
    int get_id() const;
    void set_id(int _id);
};
```

And then create pragmas for that class in another file

```
#pragma db object(basic_object) abstract
#pragma db member(basic_object::_id) get(get_id) set(set_id) id auto
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can, it's called *named pragmas*.

In your other file you would have to write

```
#pragma db object(basic_object)
#pragma db member(basic_object::_id) id
```

---

Then you have to tell the odb compiler where to look for. You can either do this by adding

```
#ifdef ODB_COMPILER
#include "other_file.hxx"
#endif
```

to your original file **OR**
by using

> --odb-epilogue  '#include "other_file.hxx"'

as parameter to the odb compiler.

---

But there is one problem in the example class `basic_object` you had given: Your data field `_id` is private. You can fix this by

declaring it public

**or**

by adding the odb access class as a friend in your class with:

```
private:
friend class odb::access;
```

Comment: thanks for answering!
For now I already solve problem, but forgot add own solution to topic(
In addition to yours answer, I wanna say that not necessarily to make `_id` public or add friend class. Newest versions of ODB Compiler is able to parse/use yours public getters and setters if they fit in common style, or you can add own regex to find their

Comment: @Dcow Nice to know thanks (I guess they said this on the mailing list? Didn't read it in the manual)